# break times into 30 minute chunks

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I have two dates start and end

```
"start" : "Wed Jan 27 2016 21:00:00 GMT-0500",
"end" : "Thu Jan 27 2016 23:30:00 GMT-0500"
```

I want to divide this time into chunks like follow

```
"start" : "Wed Jan 27 2016 21:00:00 GMT-0500",
"end" : "Thu Jan 27 2016 21:30:00 GMT-0500"
----------------------------------------------
"start" : "Wed Jan 27 2016 21:30:00 GMT-0500",
"end" : "Thu Jan 27 2016 22:00:00 GMT-0500"
----------------------------------------------
"start" : "Wed Jan 27 2016 22:00:00 GMT-0500",
"end" : "Thu Jan 27 2016 22:30:00 GMT-0500"
----------------------------------------------
"start" : "Wed Jan 27 2016 22:30:00 GMT-0500",
"end" : "Thu Jan 27 2016 23:00:00 GMT-0500"
----------------------------------------------
"start" : "Wed Jan 27 2016 23:00:00 GMT-0500",
"end" : "Thu Jan 27 2016 23:30:00 GMT-0500"
```

Is there anyway to do this using moment.js or javascript?

Comment: Well, not strictly without knowing the time zone, since there may be a time offset change in the middle of the interval.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I know the timezone where the date is coming from, Let's say it is `America/New_Your`, Is there any way to do this if I know timezone?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson and I have moment timezone library added too

Comment: So are you having trouble coming up with an algorithm to do this, or in implementing your algorithm in JS? Where are you stuck? Please show the relevant part of your existing code.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I have no idea how to do this, I search for a while and didn't found any answers. So from your question this is where i'm stuck "I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using moment-timezone (assuming you [added the timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/adding-a-zone/)), this will write your intervals to console.log;

```
var start = moment.tz('2016-01-27 21:00', 'America/New_York');
var end   = moment.tz('2016-01-27 23:30', 'America/New_York');

while(start < end) {
  console.log('Start: ' + start.format());
  start = start.add(30, 'minutes')
  console.log('End:   ' + start.format());
  console.log();
}

Start: 2016-01-27T21:00:00-05:00
End:   2016-01-27T21:30:00-05:00

Start: 2016-01-27T21:30:00-05:00
End:   2016-01-27T22:00:00-05:00

Start: 2016-01-27T22:00:00-05:00
End:   2016-01-27T22:30:00-05:00

Start: 2016-01-27T22:30:00-05:00
End:   2016-01-27T23:00:00-05:00

Start: 2016-01-27T23:00:00-05:00
End:   2016-01-27T23:30:00-05:00
```

Comment: If I save the time in UTC, then I don't need to do any of these conversions right?

Answer (score 3):

We can break time into chunks like this:

```js
 var time = {
   "start": "Wed Jan 27 2016 21:00:00 GMT-0500",
   "end": "Thu Jan 27 2016 23:30:00 GMT-0500"
 };


 var startTime = new Date(time.start).getTime();
 var endTime = new Date(time.end).getTime();

 var diff = endTime - startTime;

 var chunks = [];
 var hold = startTime;
 var threshold = (60 * 30 * 1000); //30minutes
 for (var i = (startTime + threshold); i <= endTime; i += (threshold)) {
   var newEndTime = new Date(i);
   chunks.push({
     start: new Date(hold),
     end: newEndTime
   });
   hold = newEndTime;
 }
 console.log(chunks)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var startTime = new Date(start).getTime();
var endTime = new Date(end).getTime();

var duration = 1000 * 60 * 30;
var times = [] ;
var arr_len = (startTime - endTime)/duration;

for(i=0; i< arr_len; i++){
    times.push(new Date(startTime + duration));
}
```

Then you get these chunks

Comment: Thanks for the answer but here the start and end times are not static, so how can we find the number of chunks here?

Comment: @Sasikanth what did you mean the start and end times are not static? I attached an image which I run those codes in console.

Comment: I mean, how can we decide on the number `5`, what if I had time from `1am to 5am`, then I will get only first 5 number of 30 minutes junks but in this case I want 8 junks

Comment: I misunderstood your question...see the new edition.